# Scipy's Curve Fit Can't Find Optimal Parameters

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I'm currently trying to give a Gaussian fit to some data files of LEDs using scipy's curve_fit tool. The method I've used for the first 3 out of 5 LEDs produces working curves, but the last 2 give similar errors.

I've added a screenshot of what one of the graphs looks like (one of the two that does not seem to work with curve_fit) as well as the cell of code where I try the fit itself.

```
error472 = data472y ** 0.5 
error505 = data505y ** 0.5 
error525 = data525y ** 0.5 
error588 = data588y ** 0.5 
error611 = data611y ** 0.5 

def GausFunc(x,a,b,c,d,f):
    return(a*np.exp(-(x-b)**2 / (2*c**2))+(d*x)+f)

popt472, pcov472 = curve_fit(GausFunc, data472x, data472y, [0.8,470,50,-10,6], error472, True)
popt505, pcov505 = curve_fit(GausFunc, data505x, data505y, [0.8,470,50,-10,6], error505, True)
popt525, pcov525 = curve_fit(GausFunc, data525x, data525y, [0.8,470,50,-10,6], error525, True)
popt588, pcov588 = curve_fit(GausFunc, data588x, data588y, [0.387,589,5,1,1], error588, True)
#popt611, pcov611 = curve_fit(GausFunc, data611x, data611y, [0.8,470,50,-10,6], error611, True)
```

The error message I am receiving:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[91], line 13
     11 popt505, pcov505 = curve_fit(GausFunc, data505x, data505y, [0.8,470,50,-10,6], error505, True)
     12 popt525, pcov525 = curve_fit(GausFunc, data525x, data525y, [0.8,470,50,-10,6], error525, True)
---> 13 popt588, pcov588 = curve_fit(GausFunc, data588x, data588y, [0.387,589,5,1,1], error588, True)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minpack_py.py:864, in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, full_output, **kwargs)
    862     cost = np.sum(infodict['fvec'] ** 2)
    863     if ier not in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
--> 864         raise RuntimeError("Optimal parameters not found: " + errmsg)
    865 else:
    866     # Rename maxfev (leastsq) to max_nfev (least_squares), if specified.
    867     if 'max_nfev' not in kwargs:

RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 1200.
```

I tried adjusting the initial guesses as much as I could, trying to narrow in on what would work, but none seem to do so (and the same initial guesses for the first 3 LEDs seemed to work just fine). I also tried increasing maxfev by quite a lot and it would produce the same error each time. It just seems to be the LED data at 588 nm and 611 nm that produce this error.

I also tried going with a base Gaussian function by removing anything involving the variables "d" and "f" in the function, which resulted in the same error of "RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 1200."

This is my first post here, so if I've forgotten any information I apologize; feel free to ask for any other needed information.

[image: plot]

Comment: Can you provide the data you're fitting on?

Comment: The txt files have 3000 lines each so I uploaded them to a onedrive folder for better access: 

https://myerauedu-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/kehlc_my_erau_edu/EmyAg_yke5FBlUnGWBjd6esBQncH0T4kgfGMSL4ZHqIFUw?e=y9acjX

Also, it seems the screenshot did not attach. I'll fix that

Comment: The issue seems to be related to how sigma is being calculated. Some elements of error588 are zero. This implies that you know Y at this point with infinite precision, and that the model should have an infinitely large penalty for mistakes at that point. Can you clarify what your intent was with the sigma?

Comment: @NickODell Huh... I went back to make a placeholder variable for the uncertainty and it now seems to work for both of the broken curves, so that was definitely the issue. The txt files of data were given to me from my professor, but was told by the lab's TA that we would need uncertainty for the fit process to work. He advised using the square root of the counts, similar to another lab I had done. I just rolled with that suggestion, did not realise it would cause errors like this

Comment: There are long tails which are essentially 0 in that data, but will have undue weighting in a least-squares fit. Maybe try curve-fitting on the data from x=500 to 650, say.

Answer (score 0):

The following MCVE performs the regression without error for all your files:

```
import pathlib
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize, stats

def model(x, loc, scale, height):
    law = stats.norm(loc=loc, scale=scale)
    return height * law.pdf(x) / law.pdf(loc)

files = list(pathlib.Path("led").glob("*.txt"))

for file in files:
    
    data = pd.read_csv(file, sep="\t", header=None, names=["x", "y"])
    popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(model, data.x, data.y, p0=[600., 20., 0.8])
    
    fig, axe = plt.subplots()
    axe.plot(data.x, data.y)
    axe.plot(data.x, model(data.x, *popt))
    axe.grid()
```

It makes use of `x` and `y` and an educated initial guess. Fit are poor because your data are far from normality.

[image]